# Why does forEach(console.log) not work?

Tags: javascript, function, logging, anonymous-function

In JavaScript, why does `.forEach(console.log)` only give you the output you expect when you wrap `console.log` in another function?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> ```
> [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> ```

```
a.forEach(console.log)
```

> ```
> 0 0 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 1 1 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 2 2 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 3 3 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 4 4 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 5 5 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> 6 6 [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> undefined
> ```

```
a.forEach(function(n) { console.log(n) })
```

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> undefined
> ```

What causes this difference in output?

Comment: It does work..! But with 3 arguments...Which are [`(currentValue, index, array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters)

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript foreach(console.log)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+foreach%28console.log%29)

Comment: @axlj it's not weird at all, `forEach` and `console.log` are working just as intended...

Comment: @axlj — "_definitely some weird behaviour_" ? What is that ?

Comment: @AndrewLi -- read the linked post.  makes sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: *console* is a host object whose behaviour isn't specified, so only the implementors know the expected behaviour.